# Redirect to new page using functional component in Card Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to learn how to redirect to my URentPage using **Link/Router** method and **onClick** . I have this card created in my UMainPage and I want to link this card to a page that i've created.

I have not written anything in my URentPage.tsx, just wrote a `h1` tag to test the page redirection:

```js
import React from 'react'

export default function URentPage(){
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Testing page navigation</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And in my `UMainPage.tsx`where my `<Card>` is located at:

```js
import RentPage from './URentPage'; //imported my page


<Card className={classes.venueCard}>
                            <CardActionArea>
                                <CardMedia
                                    className={classes.media}
                                    image = {card1}
                                    title="气膜馆"
                                />
                                <CardContent>
                                    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                                        清华大学气膜馆
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
                                        球类: 羽球场 乒乓球
                                    </Typography>
                                </CardContent>
                            </CardActionArea>
                            <CardActions className="classes.venueCardActions">
                                <PeopleIcon style={{fill:"#27496B", marginLeft:"5px", height: 35, width: 35}}/>
                                <Typography variant="body2" color="inherit">
                                    300人
                                </Typography>
                                <SportsIcon style={{fill:"#27496B", marginLeft:"50px",height: 35, width: 35}}/> 
                                <Typography variant="body2" color="inherit">
                                    10个羽球场 10个乒乓球场
                                </Typography>
                            </CardActions>
                        </Card>
```

I've done some routing here in my `App.tsx`:

```js
class App extends Component {
  render(){
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/'>Homepage</Route>
          <Route path='/rentPage' component={URentPage}/>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
  }
}
```

After running in `localhost:3000` the `rentPage` that i wanna navigate to appears right at the bottom of my `UMainPage` .

Comment: could you show any code that showed you have tried doing the routing?

Comment: @lala i've done some routing but the new page appears under my `UMainPage`

Comment: Are you saying you want to add a "navbar" below your main page? It isn't clear what your question is, or what your issue is, if you have one. Where are you trying to "redirect" from ? I don't see any `Redirect` components being rendered, nor do I see any `onClick` handlers anywhere in the snippets.

Comment: you want to `redirect` to the `rentPage` or  you want to **rendered** `rentPage` under the `UMainPage`? Please clarify your issue

Comment: @lala I wanna redirect to the `rentPage`

Comment: @DrewReese No, i just simply want to redirect to my `rentPage` from after clicking on the card. I thought `Link` would do the job so i didnt add any `onClick` or `Redirect` ..

Comment: A `Link` would work for declarative navigation, a `history.push` would work in an onClick handler for imperative navigation. Like I said though, I don't see any links or onClick handlers being used so it is unclear what and where you are attempting to do any navigation. You kind of need to show us what you are trying to do and where it isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in varies ways actually. But I'm just gonna show you **2. ways only**. Both will requires you to use `Link` imported from `react-router-dom`:-

1. make the whole card as **link** (Not recomended if you have any other `onClick` event in the card):-

```js
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const UMainPage = () => {
  return (
    <Link to="/rentPage">
      <Card>
        {/* card content here */}
      </Card>
    </Link>
  )
}
```

2. `onClick` event on `Card` with `useHistory` imported from `react-router-dom`:-

```js
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

const UMainPage = () => {
  const history = useHistory()  

  return (
    <Card onClick={() => history.push('/rentPage')}>
      {/* card content here */}
    </Card>
  )
}
```

3. create an `action` `button` or `icon`:-

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const UMainPage = () => {
  return (
    <Link to="/rentPage">
      <Card>
        <CardActions>
          <Link path="/rentPage">
            <IconButton aria-label="share">
              <ShareIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Link>
          <Link path="/rentPage">  
            <Typography>
              Go to main page
            </Typography>
          </Link>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    </Link>
  )
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the first method which is link but it's not working, i think i have to do some changes in my `App.tsx` file but i dont know what changes i have to do. I'm currently using the code that i've edited above and it works completely fine but not when i'm using `UMainPage` to replace the `HomePage`

Comment: i just update my answer. try to apply **2 option**. See whether its working or not

Comment: It works after doing some small changes on my `App.tsx` to work with the second option. Thank you!

Comment: Great! Glad able to help then.